# How do you convert an array to a nested object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested

For example, a function that would be `const arrToNestObj = arr => {}` and would get `[a, b, c, d, e]` and return

```
a: {
  b: {
     c: {
        d: {
           e: {

           }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.reduceRight()` to create a nested object:

```js
const arrToNestObj = arr => 
  arr.reduceRight((acc, key) => ({ [key]: acc }), {})

const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

const result = arrToNestObj(arr)

console.log(result)
```